# Booting linux-3.14.41 on ZC706: Kernel Panic

Tags: linux-kernel, riscv

I get the following error while booting linux-3.14.4 on FPGA ZC706. I have build all tools following ways:

Rocket-Chip:

```
$ Latest master branch is checked out and generate boot.bin

riscv-gnu-toolchain:
$ ./build.sh (riscv64-unknown-elf)
$ make linux (for riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc)

Linux kernel:
$curl -L https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.14.41.tar.xz | tar -xJkf -
$ cd linux-3.14.41
$ git init
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux.git
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -f -t origin/master
$ make ARCH=riscv defconfig
$ make -j12 ARCH=riscv vmlinux
```

Root disc image:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=root.bin bs=1M count=64
$ mkfs.ext2 -F root.bin
```

Booting:

```
1. First copy all files (vmlinux, root.bin, boot.bin, devicetree.dtb, uImage,  uramdisk.image.gz) into sdcard.
(2) $ mkdir /sdcard
$ mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /sdcard
$ ./fesvr-zynq +disk=/sdcard/riscv/root.bin bbl /sdcard/riscv/vmlinux
```

Booting starts, but stuck at a point. The following are the booting error

```
    [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
    [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
    [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
    [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
    [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
    [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 64135
    [    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/htifblk0
    [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
    [    0.000000] Memory: 253568K/260096K available (1725K kernel code, 120K rwdata, 356K rodata, 68K init, 211K bss, 6528K reserved)
    [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
    [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2
    [    0.150000] Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 20.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=100074)
    [    0.150000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
    [    0.150000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.150000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.150000] devtmpfs: initialized
    [    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
    [    0.150000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
    [    0.150000] Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
    [    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.150000] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.150000] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.150000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
    [    0.150000] TCP: reno registered
    [    0.150000] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.150000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    0.150000] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
    [    0.150000] io scheduler noop registered
    [    0.150000] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
    [    0.170000] htifcon htif1: detected console
    [    0.180000] console [htifcon0] enabled
    [    0.180000] htifblk htif2: detected disk
    [    0.180000] htifblk htif2: added htifblk0
    [    0.180000] TCP: cubic registered
    [    0.180000] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 254:0.
    [    0.180000] devtmpfs: error mounting -2
    [    0.180000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 68K (ffffffff80000000 - ffffffff80011000)
    [    0.180000] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
    [    0.180000] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 3.14.41-g2317c43-dirty #2
    [    0.180000] Call Trace:
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff80012f54>] walk_stackframe+0x0/0xc8
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff801bbff4>] panic+0xb4/0x1c4
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff80012a24>] sys_rt_sigreturn+0x140/0x178
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff801bba08>] rest_init+0x80/0x84
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff801bbafc>] kernel_init+0xf0/0xf4
    [    0.180000] [<ffffffff801bba08>] rest_init+0x80/0x84
```

Can anyone help me, whether I miss anything. I also tried with 
linux-3.14.33; the same error comes

Comment: `No working init found` seems clear enough...

Comment: Thanks Marc, for your shift reply. Can you please suggest a work around to fix this? Did I miss any steps?

Comment: you might have copied to the kernel to the boot device, but the kernel itself is basically useless without the rest of the os there. once the kern's done starting, it fires up `init`, which then starts firing up everything else. and as per the error message, you don't have `init`, or haven't pointed the kernel where it should be looking for init.

Comment: How do we build "the rest of the os"? We have followed only the steps to build the kernel image, as described in http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_linux.

Comment: Did you try running your linux and boot image on the Spike ISA simulator first?  You should verify your software is working first before trying to run this on an FPGA.

Comment: None of your excerpts shows the kernel command line. Are you sure you have it right?

Comment: The problem was with root.bin; now get resolved. Thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
I can now boot kernel on SPIKE ISA as well as FPGA. I omit some steps while building root.bin mentioned at https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools.

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=root.bin bs=1M count=64
$ mkfs.ext2 -F root.bin

will generate empty root.bin. We need to mount disc image and complete the file systems after completing busy box building as mentioned at https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools
```